# get data by id from MongoDB by using Axios Vue.js and Node.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

i want to get data from mongoDB  database but not all data from collection only one data to Update it in my Admin Page to manage my product page but by below code i can't get  and this is error in consol

```
GET http://localhost:3000/products/5edbe6e824982635ac07e859 500 (NuxtServerError)
```

and this is frontend  code in Nuxt project the file is in  ===> admin/pages/products/_id.vue

_id.vue

```
export default {
    async asyncData({$axios,params }) {
      try {

        let products= $axios.$get('http://localhost:8000/api/products,${params.id}');

        const [productsResponse] = await Promise.all([
           products
        ]);
        console.log(productsResponse);
        return {
          products:productsResponse.products
        };

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },


 data() {
      return {
        product:{
          cityID:null,
          categoryID:null,
          productname: '',
          cellphone: null,
          licensenumber: null,
          address: '',
          rating: null
        }

      };
```

and have another part about put data but as i said i have problem in get single  data in collection

**it's good to say i can get all data but can't  get single data i think there is problem in part that include {params.id}**

and backend code is

product.js

```
//GET request - get a single style
router.get("/product/:id", async (req, res) =>{
    try {
        let product = await Product.findOne({ _id:req.params.id});
        res.json({
            success:true,
            product:product
        });

    }catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success:false,
            message:err.message
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: did you try this? `$axios.$get(\`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${params.id}\`);`

Comment: @HongJian   can you give me a code that you mean , you mean i use your code without** let product** = $axios ...

Comment: i mean change this line of your code from `let products= $axios.$get('http://localhost:8000/api/products,${params.id}');` to `let products= $axios.$get(\`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${params.id}\`);`

Comment: @HongJian tahnks about it,  give another err do you know what's that?===>[Vue warn]: Property or method "cities" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

Comment: "cities is not defined". Thats mean u use "cities" somewhere else but it is undefined. Your post has not enough information to solve this problem. can u show your template code? or all the code of this vue component

Comment: @HongJian plaese tell me what's the problem in below

Answer (score 1):

according to nuxt documentation. asyncData return value will be merged with data value. For example, async data return project, then data should return project as  well

```
export default {
  data () {
    return { project: 'default' }
  },
  asyncData (context) {
    return { project: 'nuxt' }
  }
}
```

try changing your data to this. Declare default value of cities and categories

```
      data() {
        return {
          product:{
            cityID:null,
            categoryID:null,
            productname: '',
            cellphone: null,
            licensenumber: null,
            address: '',
            rating: null
          },
          cities: [],
          categories: []
        };
      },
```

your asyncData return value {cities,categories,product}. But data only return value {product}. As default of data don't have cities value, so cities is undefined when template start rendering.

Comment: i'm really really really really really really really  thank you